# How to insert name of a cell into another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column F is a list of constants. Each cell is named. I want to insert the name of each cell in Column F into an adjacent cell in Column E.

For example F9 is named "FeetPerMeter" and has a value of 3.28084.
I want the value of E9 to be the text string  "FeetPerMeter".

Comment: That will require vba, formulas cannot return the range name.  There are bound to be many examples of how to do this with vba out there.  What research have you done?

Comment: You could write the name of each cell in an adjacent column as a formula.  `=FeetPerMeter`, then use FORMULATEXT  to extract the names in a string.

Comment: Oh while this may seem fruitless i.e. if you have to type each name as a formula why not just type it as text? Well for one, if you type = and then move the cursor to a named cell, it will return the name instead of the reference. You could do this in a single formula i.e. =FeetPerMeter + dimension + blahblah, then extract the formula text and use the + sign as delimiter to split the text into individual cells

Comment: Alternatively press F3 and "paste list". Then sort and filter by references provided and copy and paste into column E.

Comment: Thanks, Mobus , for your help. The FORMULATEXT worked perfectly! It is just what I was looking for.